# __weak and autorelease pool in ARC in Xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode4.2, automatic-ref-counting, autorelease, weak

My project use ARC. I tested with the code below:

> ```
> NSString __weak *string;
> @autoreleasepool {
>         string = [NSString stringWithString:@"AAA"];
> }
>
> NSLog(@"string: %@", string);
> ```

I think it output as:

```
string: (null)
```

but it actually output:

```
string: AAA
```

I don't understand it. What is the effect of __weak?

EDIT:

And this code below:

> ```
> NSString __weak *string;
> NSString __strong *str;
> @autoreleasepool {
>     str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"AAA" ];
>     string = str;
> }
>
> NSLog(@"string: %@", string);
> ```

It also output as:

```
string: AAA
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
NSString __weak *string;
@autoreleasepool {
        string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"AAA"];
}

NSLog(@"string: %@", string);
```

it outputs as the following what you want.

```
string: (null)
```

Thus,

```
string = [NSString stringWithString:@"AAA"];
```

is same as

```
string = @"AAA";
```

the constant string literal that is not allocated in the heap.

**EDITED:**

str variable has still strong reference for the autoreleased object.

The following code is what exactly you want.

```
NSString __weak *string;
{
    NSString __strong *str;
    @autoreleasepool {
        str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"AAA" ];
        string = str;
    }
}
NSLog(@"string: %@", string);
```

And

```
NSString __weak *string;
@autoreleasepool {
    NSString __strong *str;
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"AAA" ];
    string = str;
}
NSLog(@"string: %@", string);
```

Comment: Your explanation is perfect. But I have one more question in the EDIT. Please explain me!